# PHP exec() not reading output

Tags: java, php, jar, output, exec

I have a **jar** file that writes something to `stdout`. I need to execute it from PHP and store what it writes.

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Something...");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the following script

```
<?php
    exec('java -jar Main.jar', $output);
    print_r($output);
?>
```

always shows that `$output` is an empty `Array()`.

**How do I force the output go to PHP?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
<?php
    exec('java -jar StringGenerator.jar $parameter 2>&1', $output);
    header("Location: /someURL/$output[0]");
?>
```

`2>&1`ensures that the output goes to the PHP handler.

Comment: @M.C. what does the parameter you pass in look like?